# how to make a 3 attempts login form using javascript by verifying cookie stored value and ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, codeigniter-3

```
i want to make a 3 attempts login form by storing username and password inside cookies and then check it with the ajax response values. if it matched login succesfull otherwise allow 2 more attempts and finally blocked. my code segment is here 

    <input type="hidden" id="attempt" value="3">
<p id="footer"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
while(1)
{
    var d_name=prompt("username","done");
    if(d_name != "")
        var d_password=prompt("password","done");
   document.cookie = "name="+d_name;
    document.cookie = "password="+d_password;
    var attempt = document.getElementById("attempt").value;
    if(d_name != "" && d_password != "")
    {
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>",
    data:{
        d_name:d_name,
        d_password:d_password
    },
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(result) {
        var u = result[0].d_name; 
        var v = result[0].d_password; 
        alert(u);
    },
error: function(result) { console.log(result); }
 });
        if (document.cookie['name'] == 'u' && document.cookie['password'] == 'v') 
        {
            alert('success'); 
            break;
        }       
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("attempt").value = attempt -1;
            alert("You have left "+(attempt-1)+" attempt;");
            attempt = attempt - 1;
            if( attempt == 0)
            {
                alert('you are blocked'); 
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i want to verify my logging username and password stored in cookies document.cookie['name'] and document.cookie['password'] with ajax response values stored in variables u and v.If verification succesfull redirect otherwise allow 2 more attempts.even after if fails, blocked.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very bad way of authenticating a user. Firstly, Javascript should not have access to server-side cookie data, especially ones dealing with authentication.

Secondly, authentication via Javascript is generally frowned upon, as the code can be altered in unpredictable ways by the client. Specifically, storing values such as the attempt remaining in Javascript is very dangerous, since anyone can give themselves an unlimited amount of attempts.

Lastly, the client should never be given the password, not even a hashed password. All it would take is a quick DOM edit with `alert(document.cookie['password']);` and anyone visiting your site will instantly know what the password is.

Please refer to [this article](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php) (thanks to @Baracuda078) about a secure password login form.

As far as actually keeping track of the amount of logins, the easiest way is to use PHP session variables to store how many times the user has tried to log in. A basic explanation of sessions can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp).

For example, in the PHP file:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['auth_attempts'])){
    $_SESSION['auth_attempts'] = 0;
}
else if($_SESSION['auth_attempts'] > 3){ // More than 3 attempts
    // Handle however you wish
}
```

Each time the form is submitted and the PHP is executed, increment `$_SESSION['auth_attempts']` by 1.

Comment: ok thank you for valuable information ....but i want to make a 3 attempts login form and iam using codeigniter framework.

Comment: @Austin Added a reference to PHP session variables for storing the amount of attempts

Comment: A PHP session is also not a great solution. If he close his browser or remove his PHPSESSID coockie he can try it again. Try to save the IP address and check how many times this IP try to login for some websites I also save the user-agent. You can also add a sleep() function after a bad login attempt to slowdown bruteforce logins

Comment: And please do not use the article about a secure password login form he shared on a live server, the code is vulnerable for sql injections and you should never save plain text passwords in your database always use a password hash function https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php is maybe a better example with also security in mind